# JUnit test console multiple user inputs && passing tests that are meant to fail

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Problem 1:I have program that prompts for input and one of the options is to select option 't' meaning to get info from a text file. The user is than prompted to input the name of the text file as well.

Problem 2: 
testE()
testF()

are both meant to fail to show validation input. How can I show them as passed?

Here is what my test looks like so far, most of them are single input

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import package.App;

import org.junit.Test;

public class AppTest {

    @Test
    public void testA(){
        testApp("1");       
    }
    @Test
    public void testB(){
        testApp("2");       
    }
    @Test
    public void testC(){
        testApp("3");       
    }
    @Test
    public void testD(){
        testApp("a");       
    }
    @Test
    public void testE(){
        testApp("hello");       
    }
    @Test
    public void testF(){
        testApp("");
    }
    @Test
    public void testG(){
        testApp("t");
    }

    public void testApp(String a){
        System.out.println();
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(a.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        App.main(null);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This is the main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter '1' , '2' or '3' for individual calulations based on formatted input from the given problem" + "\n" + 
        "Enter 't' for input from a text file");
        System.out.print("Please select the mode from which to run:");

        String input = "";
        input = scan.nextLine();

        while(input.length()!= 1){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Invalid input, valid entries. Please try again.");
            System.out.println("Enter '1' , '2' or '3' for individual calulations based on formatted input from the given problem" + "\n" + 
            "Enter 't' for input from a text file");
            System.out.print("Please select the mode from which to run:");
            input = scan.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println();   
        char c = input.charAt(0);
        new ProductList(c);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not obvious what you App class is doing.

Comment: I can edit to show main class

Comment: Suggestion: Make string array with those values and iterate through the values in a test.

Answer (score 1):

Can't do it that way.

Stop for a moment and **think about what you are trying to test**. Certainly not the functionality of Java console input, but rather the outcome of your calculation, correct?

Refactor the code to separate data input from calculation. Get rid of logic in static methods, especially the main method. Use object orientation to create proper components, maybe a `Calculator` and a `DataProvider`? **Static main would only wire things together**, no other logic.

**Write test against the Calculator, but this time wire it together from within the test**, and a different DataProvider that you can provide with test values for the test (but that has nothing to do with cosole).

Write lots of cool unit tests now :)

Comment: No, im not trying to test the output of my calculations, because I know that it works. I need to test the functionality of my program by giving inputs that show the results. I have two other classes that handle calculations, provide data and even store objects with specific traits for calculations. But I can see where you are going, testing the functions instead of the main class that takes inputs because is only used to bring them together.